# Customizing UIBarButtonItem in Objective C

Tags: ios

I am trying to add image to UIBarButtonItem in IOS App. I am able to add it but the problem is image is taking the size of the button. But I want button to be of the size of the image with borders included in it.

Comment: why dont u add a UIButton with custom type with image u have and place where you want...

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customButtonBgImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customButtonImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
```

And the you can add barButtonItem where-ever you need it.